# XCode and updated SVN

Tags: svn, xcode

the stock svn that comes with OSX is 1.4.4 and I upgraded (through opencollab installers) to 1.6.2

My Problem is, XCode (v3.1.2) picks up the old subversion.  At one point I had fixed this by executing the following:

```
defaults write ~/.MacOSX/environment DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/subversion/lib
```

And it worked.  But it has since reverted to not working again :(

The error message I get is:

> Error: 155021 (Unsupported working copy format) Description: This client is too old to work with working copy '/Users/craiger/workspace/Onshore/Mapp'; please get a newer Subversion client

Anyone know how to fix this once and for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [this method](http://www.lemonteam.com/blog/2008/12/setting-up-subversion-15-on-xcode/) on XCode from iPhone SDK 2.2 and SVN 1.6 and it has survied upgrade to SDK 3.0 (XCode 3.1.3).

```
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libapr-1.dylib /usr/lib/libapr-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libapr-1.dylib /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libaprutil-1.dylib /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libaprutil-1.dylib /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_client-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_client-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_delta-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_delta-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_fs_fs-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_fs_fs-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_fs_fs-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_fs_fs-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_fs-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_fs-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_fs-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_fs-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_ra_local-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_local-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_ra_local-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_local-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_ra-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_ra-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_ra-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_ra-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_wc-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_wc-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_repos-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_repos-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_repos-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_repos-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_subr-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_subr-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_subr-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_delta-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_delta-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_delta-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_delta-1.0.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_diff-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.dylib
ln -s -f /opt/subversion/lib/libsvn_diff-1.dylib /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.0.dylib
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that method floating around the web but I couldn't believe it would take all that to make it work!  I'll give it a shot and report back